# Вертикальное выравнивание текста в Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как выровнять номера по центру? align-middle не помогает

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Заявка или звонок</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Встреча</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Договор и оплата</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Доставка</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте классу

```
.align-middle {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

ну или в стилях, которые inline, раз уж они есть.

```
style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;line-height: 40px;"
```

```css
.align-middle {
  line-height:40px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Заявка или звонок</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Встреча</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Договор и оплата</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
        <center>
          <p class="align-middle" style="width:40px;height: 40px;font-weight: 800;background:black;border-radius:40px;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">1</p>
        </center>
        <p style="font-weight:800">Доставка</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```